# Can users of Rinne Rebirth exchange other's life to revive someone?

Tags: naruto

For example, if Nagato use Ningendo and extract soul from someone, can that soul be used for reviving someone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common misconception is that a life is needed for the Rinne Rebirth.Let me clear that first.

During Pain's fight with Naruto,when Pain becomes good,he uses the Rinne Rebirth to revive everyone he's killed.At that point,Konan tells him that he doesn't have enough chakra to cast such a powerful jutsu.

So you need a large amount of chakra to pull off the Rinne Rebirth-which is often confused with the life of a person.You could die because of the exhaustion though.

Now coming to your question.

Yes,it is possible if the life force of the person from whom you've pulled the soul out is enough for the jutsu to be cast.

Example:You can't expect a 5 year old boy's life force to be enough for the Rinne Rebirth.

Comment: I find it very strange so many people think it kills the user, considering it was very clear that Nagato died of exhaustion, and Obito didn't die at all. In fact, besides the literal suicide moves like Deidaras self powered nuke, most "kill you after you use it" techniques/pills actually killed you via forced exhaustion of all chakra and not only could be prevented, but were prevented thanks to special circumstances. Even Biju extraction damage could be reversed with a sacrifice of life force or resealing of the biju, both of which happened. That being said, the answer part is speculation

Answer (score 1):

not really, but the jutsu just retract enormous amount of chakra from once body which people dont normally survive because of the exhaustion after the jutsu has taken effect, one of the events this happened was when Naruto was battling the seven pain, his sibling nagato, konan but that was after Naruto defeated them. and went where the seven pains main chakra was generating